Abstract root systems in positive characteristic
Does anyone know of a reference outlining the theory of abstract root systems in positive characteristic?
In the hope of inciting useful remarks, I'll outline how I imagine such a theory might be developed below.
Given a field $k$ and two perfectly-paired (thus finite-dimensional) vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over $k$, I claim a root system $R$ with indexing set $I$ is:

a set of roots $\{r_i ~|~ i \in I\} \subset V$
a set of coroots $\{c_i ~|~ i \in I\} \subset W$
a set of permutations $\{\sigma_i ~|~ i \in I\} \subset \operatorname{Sym}(I)$

such that:

the maps $i \mapsto r_i$ and $i \mapsto c_i$ are injective (so we have a bijection between roots and coroots)
$\langle c_i, r_i \rangle = 2$ for all $i$
$r_{\sigma_i (j))} = r_j - \langle c_i, r_j \rangle r_i$ for all $i$, $j$
$c_{\sigma_i (j))} = c_j - \langle c_j, r_i \rangle c_i$ for all $i$, $j$
the roots span $V$
the coroots span $W$

If $\langle c_i, r_j \rangle \in k_Z$ for all $i$, $j$, where $k_Z$ is the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $k$ under $n \mapsto n \cdot 1$, we say $R$ is crystallographic.
If $I$ is finite we can define a bilinear form on $V$ by $B_V = \sum c'_i \otimes c'_i$, where $c_i' \in V^*$ corresponds to $c_i \in W$ under the perfect pairing. Likewise we can define $B_W$ on $W$. I will call the root system anisotropic if $B_V(r_i, r_i) \ne 0$ and $B_W(c_i, c_i) \ne 0$ for all $i$.
If $R$ is anisotropic it's not too hard to show that $B_V$ and $B_W$ are non-singular (in fact in this case we don't even need to assume the coroots span $W$ since this follows).
If $k$ has characteristic zero and $R$ is crystallographic then it's also not too hard to show that $R$ is anisotropic.
In fact, in characteristic zero (still assuming $I$ is finite) the axioms may be weakened in numerous ways. For example the coroots are uniquely determined by the roots, $\sigma$ is uniquely determined, and the equation for $c_{\sigma_i (j)}$ can be deduced from the one for $r_{\sigma_i (j)}$.
It seems to me that much of the familiar theory for finite, crystallographic root systems in characteristic zero should carry over to finite, anisotropic, crystallographic root systems in characteristic $p > 5$. However I have failed to find a reference. I have looked at Seligman's Modular Lie Algebras and I think that roots of finite-dimensional Lie algebras with non-singular Killing form are a finite, anisotropic, crystallographic root root system if the coefficients are a perfect field of positive characteristic $p > 5$. So if there is a coherent theory of abstract root systems in positive characteristic, then presumably this much is implicit in Seligman. However I don't think he has developed this theory on its own, but rather just studied the roots of a Lie algebra. Hence my headline question.
I might add that various versions of the above hold with weaker assumptions on the coefficients (e.g., integral domain rather than field) and apply to root data (if we drop the spanning conditions) but the story there is a good deal more subtle (bringing in arithmetic issues of a different nature) so I wish to suppress it here.

Do you require that $i \mapsto r_i$ and $i \mapsto c_i$ are bijections? \ Does "$\langle c_i, r_j\rangle \in \mathbb Z$" mean that it lies in the prime subfield? Or maybe "perfectly paired" doesn't mean the pairing is valued in $k$?

@LSpice Thanks for these questions, I have edited to try to clarify these points. To answer you directly here:

Yes, the maps $i \mapsto r_i$ and $i \mapsto c_i$ are injective (thus bijective to their images)
The $\mathbb{Z}$ appearing in $\langle c_i, r_j \rangle \in \mathbb{Z}$ was sloppily-written and suppose to indicate the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $k$ under $n \mapsto n \cdot 1 = 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1$
The perfect pairing does take values in $k$ (I appreciate why you asked this given the sloppiness in 2). To be precise it is a $k$-bilinear map $V \otimes W \to k$ such that...


...such that the induced maps $V \to W^$ and $W \to V^$ are bijective.
If you really want precision I have authored a formal version of all of this in Lean here: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/LinearAlgebra/RootSystem/Defs.html#RootPairing

Thanks!  Of course (1) is very picky indeed; I just thought I'd check in case there was some wrinkle in requiring an indexing set with common maps to roots and coroots, rather than a bijection from roots to coroots.  But (2) seems more interesting to me because it means that all root systems over a positive-characteristic prime field are crystallographic, so that any non-crystallographic ones are carrying some arithmetic information about ground fields—as opposed to the characteristic-$0$ situation, where extending the field offers no new possibilities.

@LSpice Yes, and I'm not really sure what to make of this. It has occurred to me that one could say a system $R$ is "prime-valued" if $\langle c_i, r_j\rangle$ takes values in the prime subfield. With this definition, things line up across characteristics and the special thing in positive characteristic is that prime-valued implies crystallographic.

@LSpice it sounds absurde to assume that $i\mapsto r_i$ is surjective (which is implied by "bijective"). The standard word for "bijection onto its image" is "injection".
